# Calculate $\mathbb EX$, $VarX$ for $\tau=\inf \{t>0: \int_0^t e^{-(W_2^2+2W_s)}ds=2\}, X=\int_0^{\tau}e^{-(\frac{W_s^2}2+W_s)}dW_s$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

> Let $$\tau=\inf \{t>0: \int_0^t e^{-(W_2^2+2W_s)}ds=2\}$$ and $$X=\int_0^{\tau}e^{-(\frac{W_s^2}2+W_s)}dW_s.$$ Please determine $\mathbb EX$, $VarX$ carefully justifying all transitions.

$$\mathbb EX=\mathbb E \left( \int_0^{\tau}e^{-(\frac{W_s^2}2+W_s)} dW_s \right) $$
$$Var X= \mathbb EX^2 = \mathbb E \int_0^{\tau} \left( e^{-(\frac{W_s^2}2+W_s)} \right)^2ds$$

Unfortunately, I cannot calculate any of these values. In particular, so far I have dealt with integrals with limits from $0$ to $t$, here an additional difficulty arises in the form of the limit of integration up to $\tau$,

Comment: Is it really $W_2^2$ in the definition of $\tau$, and not $W_s^2$?

Comment: @Snoop Yes, I checked again after your question, but everything is correct.

Comment: Alright. This is because if it were the case I mentioned, as a first approach I would see if [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubins%E2%80%93Schwarz_theorem) applies.

Comment: What is $\tau_{t_1}\,?$

Comment: In writing $Var(X) = E(X^2)$, you've decided that $E(X) = 0$. This is indeed true for the case where you have a stopped martingale that starts at zero and satisfies the conditions of the optional stopping theorem. However, your $\tau$, which depends on $W_2$, isn't even a stopping time, so such an argument couldn't be made. Like @Snoop, I wonder if you have defined $\tau$ correctly.